# How to sort an array based on its transformation

Tags: ruby, sorting

I would like to sort an array:

```
initial_array = ['23', '504', '2']
```

based on the sum of each element's digits. Transformed array is:

```
[5, 9, 2]
```

Sorting the array by the mapping:

```
chars.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
```

gives the sorted transformed array:

```
sorted_transformed_array # => [2, 5, 9]
```

The sorted initial array is:

```
['2', '23', '504']
```

How do I sort `initial_array` based on `sorted_transformed_array`? Is there a method that does this?

What is the difference from the `sort_by!` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use that transformation/calculation in combination with `sort_by` method

Before ruby 2.4

```
array.sort_by { |item| item.chars.map(&:to_i).reduce(0, :+) }
```

Since ruby 2.4

```
array.sort_by { |item| item.chars.map(&:to_i).sum }
```

Comment: Or `item.to_i.digits.sum`